# sql code : SELECT * FROM table WHERE column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table name "Coupon" and I work with java on eclipse.

I have a method getCoupon(long id); that gives me the coupon by its id and I wrote it this way:

```
public Coupon getCoupon(long id) {
        Connection con = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Coupon WHERE TYPE=?";
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
            pstmt.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    coupon.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                    coupon.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
                    coupon.setStartDate(rs.getDate(3));
                    coupon.setEndDate(rs.getDate(4));
                    coupon.setAmount(rs.getInt(5));
                    coupon.setType(CouponType.valueOf(rs.getString(6)));
                    coupon.setMessage(rs.getString(7));
                    coupon.setPrice(rs.getDouble(8));
                    coupon.setImage(rs.getString(9));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Coupon ID: " + id + " could not be found\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            CouponSystemException ex = new CouponSystemException("Coupon ID: " + id + " could not be retrieved\n", e);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(con);
        return coupon;
    }
```

I would like to make another method that it gives me the coupon by it's type! But the TYPE COLUMN isn't in the first column and it gives me exceptions.
Any advice?

Comment: first advice... format your question

Comment: What exception are you getting? What is the problem on getting the row by other column? Give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try referring to the column by name rather than ordinal position:

```
rs.getLong("type")
```

rather than:

```
rs.getLong(1)
```

Sometimes tables get re-created in a way that changes the column order, so relying on the ordinal position of the column fails.

As a further defence, I always list the columns I want, rather than coding;

```
select * ...
```

This is also more efficient since your Java program does not pull back all the columns, only those that it needs.

Comment: OK.  I'd like to help and you'll need to tell me a bit more before I can.  I think the code you show us above is working and you want to do something similar, is that right?  If so can you show us the code that fails.  We'll also need the exception you are getting.  It would also help to have the table definition (with columns and data-types) and the brand of database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First :
It looks like that you have problem in the code as follow

`String sql = "SELECT * FROM Coupon WHERE TYPE=?";`

I think that `TYPE=?` should be read as `ID=?`

Second :
As I see the `TYPE` column is string (because of `coupon.setType(CouponType.valueOf(rs.getString(6)));`) so you have to change `pstmt.setLong(1, id);` to `pstmt.setString(1, couponType.getValue());`

Third:
Always avoid `SELECT *` rather type all the columns that you need.

Forth:
Try to generalize the two methods `getCouponByID(long id)` and `getCouponByType(CouponType couponType)` so the future maintenance will be easier.

Fifth:
Put `ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnConnection(con);` in `finally` clause so you will be sure to return back the connection to the pool.

Sixth:
Using `PreparedStatement` has less performance if you use it less than many times (i.e. 100 times), and you used it only once. Using `Statement` in this case has better performance but be careful with SQL Injection if you insert user type String. In this case, don't worry cause it is a `long` type.